# Macbook Pro (mid 2017) occasionally turns on after battery replacement but shows battery with X in top corner if it does

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

How do diagnose this? How to proceed?

Did a simple battery replacement. How to test anything to do with that in a minimal way? Are screws and case required to be able to detect battery? Are there any safeties on a macbook that will interfere with testing?

I have the case base on but have not fully screwed things in. Will try to return battery if nothing comes of this.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to make sure your logic board is fully installed and that none of your cables are loose. Lastly before testing plug in your battery data cable (step 12), as well as your battery screw (step 13) before powering on to check your battery's health. Sometimes your logic board's battery connector will not properly line up with the battery before it is being screwed back in which will result in the system not thinking a battery is installed, so double-check to make sure it is lined up properly.

You can use coconutBattery (which is free) to check the health of the battery you received once the system powers on. Cycles should be showing either 0 or 1 if it is new, and design capacity should be at 100%.

SMC and PRAM resets are also recommended to make sure the system recognizes the newly installed hardware.

Hope this helps.

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Touch+Bar+2017+Battery+Replacement/123894

(same goes for 13" machines if that is what you have)